# Implementing FIFO (first in first out) in sql

Tags: sql, mysql, fifo

I have a table of stock

| ID | Qty | DatePurchased | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11202 | 4 | 01/01/2023 | 3 |
| 11202 | 3 | 12/06/2023 | 7 |
| 5050 | 4 | 11/10/2023 | 60 |
| 11202 | 4 | 12/10/2023 | 5 |
| 5050 | 8 | 12/12/2023 | 70 |

and Item sold table

| ID | Qty |
| --- | --- |
| 11202 | 6 |

I want to implement the FIFO concept where I can find the total price as follows
I have Quantity purchased in [stock table] on different dates. And I have quantity sold in table [item sold]

let us say I sold 6 quantities for a specific item in my case item "11202" I want to find the total price bymultiplyingy (quantity purchased * price ) // for the first order then multiply the next

4 * 3 = 12 (first order in date 01/01/2023) remaining stock 0

2 * 7 = 14 (second order in date 12/06/2023) remaining stock 1

12 + 14 = 26 total price

I have joined tables which look something like this
[joined table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmXYd.png)
but I don't know how to add a new column that will include remaining items and the total price

Comment: Replace images with formatted text for better response. Many of the best people won't look at posts with images.

Comment: Possibly relevant https://sqlperformance.com/2021/12/t-sql-queries/supply-demand-challenge

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to create intervals using the cumulative sums of stock and sales, and then join based on the overlaps:

```sql
WITH stock_intervals AS (
    SELECT *,
        SUM(Qty) OVER w - Qty AS IntervalStart,
        SUM(Qty) OVER w AS IntervalEnd
    FROM stock
    WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY DatePurchased)
),
sales_intervals AS (
    SELECT *,
        SUM(Qty) OVER w - Qty AS IntervalStart,
        SUM(Qty) OVER w AS IntervalEnd
    FROM sales
    WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Dt)
)
SELECT s.ID, s.DatePurchased, s.Qty, s.Price,
    LEAST(d.IntervalEnd, s.IntervalEnd) - GREATEST(d.IntervalStart, s.IntervalStart) AS tQty,
    s.Price * (LEAST(d.IntervalEnd, s.IntervalEnd) - GREATEST(d.IntervalStart, s.IntervalStart)) AS tPrice
FROM stock_intervals s
JOIN sales_intervals d
  ON s.ID = d.ID
  AND s.IntervalStart < d.IntervalEnd
  AND d.IntervalStart < s.IntervalEnd
ORDER BY s.ID, s.DatePurchased;
```

Note: I added the `Dt` column to sales so there was something to order by for the cumulative sum. Presumably you have a unique id that could be used here.

Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/pEA_z52B).

Answer (score -1):

If you want the the total price of each entry:

```
SELECT date, qty, sold_qty*price AS total FROM <joined_table> WHERE id = <id> ORDER BY date ASC;
```

If you want the total earned money for items:

```
SELECT id, MIN(qty), SUM(sold_qty * price) AS total
FROM joined_table
GROUP BY id;
```

assuming your quantity always go down, if you want the latest entry's quantity you should use a subquery.

You should substitute the code you used to join the table with `joined_table`

Comment: please note here I'm using First In First Out concept, so you can not just use any item's price 
first it should be the first item in if that item is all consumed then you will use the second item's price